# Algorithm to add, edit and remove elements and update the value of the other ones

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I'm currently working on a system and I need some help. I have a database table that stores some info about customers.

Each record has a payment date and an amount to pay. For example:

```
Customer 1, 2015-06-15, $10
Customer 1, 2015-06-30, $10
Customer 1, 2015-07-15, $10
Customer 2, 2015-06-14, $15
Customer 2, 2015-06-20, $15
...
```

Each customer has a total amount to pay (Customer 1 needs to pay $30, Customer 2 $30, etc). The total amount is stored in a different table of the database. Now, if someone adds a new payment for Customer 1, the system should update the other payments (for example, if the new payment has an amount of $6, then we need to subtract $6 from the other 3 payments. In this case, the records for Customer 1 should be updated to:

```
Customer 1, 2015-06-15, $8
Customer 1, 2015-06-30, $8
Customer 1, 2015-07-15, $8
Customer 1, 2015-07-30, $6
...
```

Because Customer 1 needs to pay $30 and since we are adding a new extra $6, we need to split the changes for all the existing records.

The same if someone edits or delete one of the records.

The idea is always keep the total amount as the same by updating all the records when the user performs an add/edit/delete operation.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: One way is to use database triggers. They act when the table is updated, an insert is done or some delete an entry. If you have an mysql database i can give you an example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @v.eigler. Unfortunately I need to achieve this via code (in this specific case, via php).

Comment: well i gave you the example with triggers. Thats my favorite way but you can also do that in PHP if the changes will be made with php.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for a trigger thats solve your problem.
You can add Trigger BEFORE or AFTER INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE on a specific table.
To split the amount of payment to the single invoice records (i think that what you described are invoices) you have to count the incoices and than divide the amount of the payment with that count (sry for my eng.). 
With `NEW.***` you can access the Data that will be inserted or updated. I think you should use `OLD.***` on BEFORE DELETE but im not shure.

```
CREATE TRIGGER on_new_payment BEFORE INSERT ON payments
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE countpayment INT;
SET countpayment = (SELECT count(*) FROM table_invoices where customer=NEW.customer);
UPDATE table_invoices SET amount = amount - (NEW.amount / countpayment) where customer = NEW.customer;
END;
```